# Rails template rendering (JS instead of HTML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

Is it possible to render only Javascript file instead of HTML for Rails action.

For example action 'index':

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

I would like the file "index.js.erb" to be called instead of "index.html.erb".

Answer (score 1):

Use [respond_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) .

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

This means client can only ask for JS response. [More about MimeResponds](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html)

Comment: It results in "ActionController::UnknownFormat" error